# How to delay reading the body of the trigger HTTP request until later in an Azure Function?

Tags: azure-functions

I am using Azure Functions to handle large (>20MB) files encoded in base64 and passed inside a Json.

Before reading and parsing the JSON body, I need to authenticate the client via an API key passed in the header of the HTTP request.

Analyzing the logs, it seems that the entire JSON is read before even executing the function.

Is there a way I can delay the reading of the JSON body until after I authenticated the user?

**Edit:**

The function is declared like this:

```
public static class V1Functions
{

    [FunctionName("V1MyFunction")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> MyFunction(
        [HttpTriggerAttribute(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "v1/my_function")] HttpRequest request,
        ILogger logger)
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that a 20MB base64-encoded file in a JSON is far from a good practice, but ::shrug:: those are the reqs.

Comment: Can you modify the client in any way? For example, to send you a HEAD request w/ API key before the POST with the payload. You could then return a challenge header that they need to include in the POST.

Comment: Actually, since you're asking, you probably can't :). Your function code triggers after the request body has been read into the request object (which is then passed into your code). I'd say drop it and switch to something raw like ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @evilSnobu do you know if the functions filters (eg OnExecutingAsync) could help?

Comment: I did not know of their existence. Looks promising. I'd raise an issue here and ask the developers of Azure Functions - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/

Comment: @Victor How is your function declared? Or rather, how does your bindings look like?

Comment: @eli Thanks. I added an example of the declaration/bindings. Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @Victor I've undeleted the answer, I'm not sure if it is of use for you though, as I'm unsure when the contents of the http request is handled.

Comment: Is the API key custom or is it azure functions API key? If it's functions, then you can just switch the AuthorizationLevel from Anonymous to other appropriate value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure app service built-in authentication and authorization support(easy auth) to authenticate users. Details about Azure app service easy auth see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization).

Azure functions are based on Azure app service, so it is enabled for Azure functions too.

[This section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#how-it-works) indicates how it works:

[image]

> Every incoming HTTP request passes through it before being handled by
>   your application code.

I think this is the auth way that you are looking for: not handle request data in your code before users are authenticated.
[This blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stuartleeks/2018/02/19/azure-functions-and-app-service-authentication/) will be helpful for you to use Azure function and Easy Auth.

Hope it helps.

Comment: He can't. You missed the part where he  reads the API key from headers.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, where the incoming request had to be authenticated before executing. However, I did not really care about the size of the content (it should never reach e.g. ~20MB). Thus, I'm not sure if this approach actually fits your needs.

As you stated in your comment `OnExecutingAsync` can be used for placing code to be executed before the function itself. The problem is, that `OnExecutingAsync` is just a task; you can't really return anything from it - which would be nice if it was possible to do, as it would allow us to return e.g. "Unauhorized", which usually is the case when talking about http requests.

In any case, whether it adheres to your requirements or not, here goes: As I see it, the request holds the contents as a stream, and afaik it hasn't been processed by the http trigger pipeline yet, at least not 'till you call e.g. `ReadAsStringAsync` or something like that.

Use a BaseController which implements `IFunctionInvocationFilter`, something like:

***Note: `IFunctionInvocationFilter` is still in preview as of 2019-12-29.***

```cs
internal abstract class BaseController : IFunctionInvocationFilter
{
    protected bool _IsAuthenticated = false;

    private IAuthenticationService _AuthenticationService;

    protected BaseController(IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
    {
        _AuthenticationService = authenticationService;
    }

    public virtual async Task OnExecutedAsync(FunctionExecutedContext executedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _IsAuthenticated = false;
    }

    public virtual async Task OnExecutingAsync(FunctionExecutingContext executingContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // This part is a tad flimsy, but I never managed to find a better way of retrieving the header values
        // You could probably investigate the FunctionExecutingContext a tad more and see if you can come up with something better

        if (executingContext.Arguments.TryGetValue("request", out var request) && request is HttpRequest httpRequest)
            _IsAuthenticated = _AuthenticationService.Authenticate(httpRequest.Headers);
        else
            _IsAuthenticated = false;
    }

    protected async Task<IActionResult> DoAuthenticated(Func<Task<IActionResult>> action)
    {
        return !IsAuthenticated ? Unauthenticated() : await action();
    }

    protected virtual IActionResult Unauthenticated()
    {
        var someErrorHandlingWithSomeModelAsBody = ...
        return new UnauthorizedObjectResult(someErrorHandlingWithSomeModelAsBody);
    }
}
```

The AuthenticationService is the capable of determining whether or not the key in the header is valid or not.

You've probably noticed the use of dependency injection (it's just how the function app I made is implemented), you could probably easily rectify this making things static as needed.

A sample controller would be something like:

```cs
public class SampleController : BaseController
{
    private readonly ISampleService _SampleService;

    public SampleController(ISampleService sampleService, IAuthenticationService authenticationService) : base(authenticationService)
    {
        _SampleService = sampleService;
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(SampleFunction))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SampleFunction(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "v1/my_function")] HttpRequest request,
        ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            return await DoAuthenticated(async () =>
            {
                var largeFileAsString = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return await _SampleService.HandleLargeFile(largeFileAsString);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // If you need exception handling...
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever `SampleFunction` is triggered, it will execute in the following order:

1. `OnExecutingAsync`-body
2. `SampleFunction`-body - the func will only be executed if the authentication is actually successful during `OnExecutingAsync`
3. `OnExecutedAsync`-body

The question is if the function actually still processes the entire 20MB of JSON content you speak of, even when the authentication fails. I'd actually personally be interested in the results if you test this.